# download latest android documentation

Tags: android, documentation

How can I download the latest documentation for android 31? I used to use the sdk manager to download the documentation. but now, I cannot seem to find the documentation in the --list of the downloadables of the sdkmanager.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use related. attention is unofficial

[Link](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-offline-documentation-download.html)

My personal recommendation

For a searchable offline documentation for Android and 130+ APIs and languages, check: Zeal (zealdocs.org) for Linux and Windows or Dash (kapeli.com/dash) for Mac.

Comment: I opened the link, but when I click on one of the provided links to download, nothing happens.

Comment: Does google provide documentation to android-31 or 30 or 29 from its own repositories? I need to download the documentation files in simple html format that I can look at from a normal browser.